# Parsing multiple dictionary columns in a dataframe to separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas data frame which has a single column containing multiple dictionaries values.

I used pd.series to flatten those dict into separate columns. Now that one column is split into 14 columns. But it still has dictionary values in every row of 14 columns.

Sample data having 14 columns in the manner A, B, C..:

```
index     A                                                                                  B                                                                C
  0      {'field_name': 'Supplier Name',                                            {'field_name': 'BG', 'user_value': None,                              {'field_name': 'VATNumber', 'user_value': None,
         'user_value': None, 'value' : 'ABCD'}                         'value': '764065'}                                                   'value': 'SE1234556'}
```

How can I further extract them as separate columns like this:

```
field_name               user_value      value
Supplier Name            None            ABCD
BG                       None            764065         
VATNumber                None            SE1234556
```

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data) #data is a list of 'values'
df1 = df['values'].apply(pd.Series)
#naming the multiple columns as A, B..
column_names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1.values, columns = column_names)
```

Comment: Some sample data would be lovely :)

Comment: if you use series then you will only get one dimention series, could you please share your code?

Comment: If you could textually paste the data it would be easier for us to reproduce. Never the less, you can try:`new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten().tolist())`

Comment: Don't post images, post data as a text so others can easily copy it to reproduce

Comment: image is not there.

Comment: I pasted the data as text now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use json_normalize to normalize the dict to columns

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.concat([json_normalize(df[c]) for c in df])

    field_name      user_value  value
0   Supplier Name   None        ABCD
0   BG              None        764065
0   VATNumber       None        SE1234556
```

Comment: I am getting an error:  AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: Please provide code to reproduce your input dataframe. This solution works with the example you gave.

Comment: I solved it. Had to remove NaN values in the dataframe. Thank you so much!